# Using Sharepoint RT editor in a JSOM form

Tags: jsom, rich-text

I'm currently creating form using JSOM manage data to replace the standard SP input forms. However, active X is not avaiable, so I do not have access to use standard third part RT editors like Tinymice for handling Rich Text. Is it possible to use the SP RT editor in a JSOM form in place of Tinymce? If so how can that be done.